# Cambiar letras por numeros en kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Por ejemplo quiero cambiar un string nombre:

```
val Nombre = "Julian"
```

y se transforme a `"Jul14n"`

Comment: Recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuales serían las reglas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto funciona:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(changeChars("Julian"));
    }

    private static String changeChars(String inputWord){
        String resp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < inputWord.length(); i++) {
            
            resp = resp + changeOneChar(inputWord.charAt(i));
        }
        return resp;
    }

    private static char changeOneChar(char aChar){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("i", "1");
        map.put("a", "4");

        String key = String.valueOf(aChar);
        String resp = "";

        resp = map.get(key);
        if (resp == null){
            resp = key;
        }

        return resp.charAt(0);
    }

}
```

Fijate que tenes una funcion `changeChars` que recorre cada letra y la manda a cambiar, y la funcion `changeOneChar` que busca en el diccionario si la letra está, y la cambia, sino la deja como está.

Podes agregar todas las letras que quieras a ese diccionnario.

Podrás criticar la solución diciendo que se instancia el `map` cada vez que se quiere cambiar un char, es un tema con `static` talvez puedas dejarla como variable global. No dudes en consultar.

Saludos
JP